# Canon EOS 80D live view shut off

Tags: live-view

When looking at menu options in live view, the screen stays on for only a few seconds.  I could not locate how to increase the time

Comment: Have you checked for a powersave mode that you can change to keep the screen on longer?

Answer (score 0):

Low battery life and camera internal temperature are two things that could cause this. I think the display should stay on for at least 30 minutes if these two conditions are normal